# Как поменять иконку маркера в Google maps?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

я использую такой код, что бы поменять иконку маркера на карте, но получаю ошибку:

```
marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon));
```

Как правильно поменять иконку?

Comment: И так, ждем же вашего решения!

Comment: Покажите ошибку.

Comment: @mit Был креш всего приложения, ошибку не выводило в Android Monitor. Я поняла в чем была ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я поняла, что было неправильно, нужно вызвать метод `icon()`, не для marker, а для `MarkerOptions`:

```
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(choosedCar)
                .title("Choosed Car")
                .snippet("Here is your taxi!")
 // поменять иконку                
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon))
// поменять цвет дефолтного маркера
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
```

И еще одна из ошибок заключалась в том, что я сгенирировала изображение маркера через `VectorAsset`, и это был вектор в формате `xml`, а нужно было, что б это было `png, jpg`,...